# C# User login handling

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I'm currently writing an application in C# (Windows 8 Windows Store App, .Net 4.5), what would highly rely on one thing I never worked before: user management.

The application to be done has to access a Windows-based server, and parse the login information with that server, then display functions, profile information, etc., based on that user data. Right now I'm stuck at the really beginning, I have no clue how to solve a global user for the whole application (pretty much like the XBox application, it would be nice to have a small user representation on the top right corner in every screen).

About the platform: we use Windows solution for user management in the whole network (there's a Microsoft ActiveDirectory server running), supplying the information for the Exchange and SharePoint servers. What I want to do is to authenticate the user with the AD server, pull the information (full name, role, access, other user data), then using these information, first display the user profile on the top right corner (the XBox Win8 app style), and load the accessible functions (this will be based on role and other domains of the user, e.g. groups).

If anyone knew a tutorial or solution what can get me closer solving this very part of the problem, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

There are specific libraries included in the .NET Framework for handling active directory requests. Take a look here:
[Generic Authentication Call to Active Directory in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778990/generic-authentication-call-to-active-directory-in-c-sharp)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316748

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. My problem is not connecting to the AD systems, but managing the user locally. I need a solution where I can store the login information thorough the whole application, and preferably save it into an encrypted storage (many apps use accounts, I want something similar)

Comment: I have done that with a singleton storing the user information. This singleton is able to communicate with my login server. I am storing all of the information on the server and the application only gets a session id. 

To the encrypted storage: You can serialize/deserialize to xml and encrypt that with an sha1 or something like that. But please be aware of storing the keys hardcoded. That would make reverse engineering easier ;)